# What is the difference between "been" and "being"?

Tags: differences, verbs, tenses

What is the difference between *been* and *being*?

Comment: You really need to supply more context to get a meaningful answer here. Perhaps you could edit the Question to include a sentence or two where you don't understand how you should choose between the two words?

Comment: "I have been eating for the last hour," "I, a human being, have been eating for the last hour," and nonstandard:  "Being as how I've been eating for the last hour..."  As you can see, they are completely different words that are used completely differently from each other.

Answer (score 3):

*Been* is the past participle of the verb *to be* and *being* is its present progressive participle (and thus is often used as a noun describing one who exists, such as a *human being*).